# data.table::fread - filter data on reading in MSWindows environment

Tags: r, windows, awk, data.table

Please help me out with correct syntax for filtering data on reading very large csv with data.table::fread in MSWindows.

For instance, I would like to keep only rows where the column sex == "T" for total, keep dates in the range of 2020-01-31 to 2020-07-01.

I came across the syntax like this but it is allegedly working only in Linux. Is there a Windows command line equivalent?:

```
mdata2 <-
  data.table::fread(
    cmd = "awk '$2 == \"T\" {print {$1}' data/demo2021-01-31_14_30_17.csv",
    nThread = 8
  )
```

What would be the correct syntax to filter the specific columns, eliminate some, use operators ==, >,< or filter values within a range of values or dates or from a specific set of values? Is there a tutorial you can recommend?

EDIT1:

The following syntax seems to work on 2nd column:

```
    mdata2 <-
  data.table::fread(
    cmd = paste('awk -F, \'$2 == "T" \'', "data/demo2021-01-30_23_59_00.csv")
  )
```

Now if I try to expand with another condition, it will not work.

```
mdata2 <-
  data.table::fread(
    cmd = paste('awk -F, \'$2 == "T" && $3 == "TOTAL" \'', "data/demo2021-01-30_23_59_00.csv")
  )
```

Trying two conditions return error. It is very confusing.

```
'(awk , '$2 == "T" && $3 == "TOTAL" ' data/demo2021-01-30_23_59_00.csv) > C:\Users\jkotows2\AppData\Local\Temp\18\Rtmp4iwcUc\file379051a52dfd' execution failed with error code 1File 'C:\Users\jkotows2\AppData\Local\Temp\18\Rtmp4iwcUc\file379051a52dfd' has size 0. Returning a NULL data.table.
```

EDIT2: After I received a supperb answer from @r2evans I tried the following syntax and it works:

```
mdata2 <-
  data.table::fread(cmd='awk "{ if (NR == 1 || ($2 == "T" && $10 == "TOTAL")) print }" data/demo2021-01-30_23_59_00.csv')
```

I will be wondering about more examples like getting only selected columns or filtering on a range of dates or a list of strings or regex. It is very interesting.

Comment: Maybe use http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm or have a look at https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-data.html

Comment: If you have Rtools installed (on windows, you should), then you have `Rtools/bin/gawk.exe` (which is gnu's `awk`). If Rtools40, then `Rtools40/usr/bin/awk.exe` (and `gawk.exe`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running on windows, you should have Rtools or Rtools40 installed. If that's the case, then you have `awk` available. (If not, then install it: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/. It's a heavy lift for just `awk`, sure, but if you haven't need it yet to install some packages, the chances are good that you will need it at some point.)

You can verify that it is available with

```r
Sys.which("awk")
#                               awk 
# "c:\\Rtools40\\usr\\bin\\awk.exe"
```

If instead you get `""`, then you need to find it. Look for the base directory where you have Rtools installed (for me, it's `C:/Rtools40/`), then set the path manually:

```r
# set up a general file for awk testing:
write.table(mtcars, file="mt.tab", sep="\t", row.names=FALSE)

### full path to awk
fread(cmd="c:/Rtools40/usr/bin/awk '{print $1}' mt.tab")[1:3,]
#      mpg
#    <num>
# 1:  21.0
# 2:  21.0
# 3:  22.8
```

(I'm not suggesting you use *this* awk code, it's just a space-filler to show that I'm using `awk` to somehow process a file that has 11 columns.)

---

For doing better filtering, something like this works:

```r
data.table::fread(cmd='awk "{ if (NR == 1 || ($2 == 4 && $10 == 4)) print }" mt.tab')
#      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#    <num> <int> <num> <int> <num> <num> <num> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1:  22.8     4 108.0    93  3.85 2.320 18.61     1     1     4     1
# 2:  24.4     4 146.7    62  3.69 3.190 20.00     1     0     4     2
# 3:  22.8     4 140.8    95  3.92 3.150 22.90     1     0     4     2
# 4:  32.4     4  78.7    66  4.08 2.200 19.47     1     1     4     1
# 5:  30.4     4  75.7    52  4.93 1.615 18.52     1     1     4     2
# 6:  33.9     4  71.1    65  4.22 1.835 19.90     1     1     4     1
# 7:  27.3     4  79.0    66  4.08 1.935 18.90     1     1     4     1
# 8:  21.4     4 121.0   109  4.11 2.780 18.60     1     1     4     2
```

- `NR == 1` is there to ensure we get the header row; if you don't have a header row, you can remove that portion of the conditional statement
- here I'm filtering for `cyl` (`$2`) of 4 and `gear` (`$10`) of 4

For clarity, the double quotes are important to how `fread` is calling `system` around the `cmd`: when I run it with doubles/singles reversed, it fails:

```r
data.table::fread(cmd="awk '{ if (NR == 1 || ($2 == 4 && $10 == 4)) print }' mt.tab")
# print was unexpected at this time.
# Warning in (if (.Platform$OS.type == "unix") system else shell)(paste0("(",  :
#   '(awk '{ if (NR == 1 || ($2 == 4 && $10 == 4)) print }' mt.tab) > C:\Users\r2\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMVUOli\filed3067f77a57' execution failed with error code 1
# Error in data.table::fread(cmd = "awk '{ if (NR == 1 || ($2 == 4 && $10 == 4)) print }' mt.tab") : 
#   File 'C:\Users\r2\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMVUOli\filed3067f77a57' does not exist or is non-readable. getwd()=='C:/Users/r2/Downloads'
```

R's `system` (and therefore `system2` and `shell`) are horrible, so it doesn't surprise me wholly that the `cmd=` is sensitive to quotes and spaces.

Comment: Sys.which("awk") indicates it is available and I can use it. It also reads the file without filtering. Next would be the syntax of awk. Can you suggest good source? csv file is comma delimited and then filter on specific columns using text, range of dates, factors?

Comment: @JacekKotowski see my edit showing filtering using `awk`.

Comment: Great. I must learn awk. May I ask you one more, how the syntax would look if one wants to filter on range of dates? Or a list of categories (eg. two specific towns, three regions out of twelve? Is it possible to refer to names of columns? I realize I will learn if I study awk more but it would make your entry very popular for windows R users, beginners like me?

Comment: I don't know if `awk` has the ability to detect *dates* per se. If not, then a range of dates would likely be done brute-force using regex or other patterns. Sorry, I know a little `awk`, not a lot. It's probably best to ask a question tagged with [tag:awk] to get the attention of stronger awk users.